# NetLogo how to count turtles in a coordinate

Tags: netlogo

im doing an evacuation model which will compare the time to take if ull take the nearest exit or go with the crowd. What i have done so far is to simulate the" nearest exit"

```
to go

ask turtles [sideway]

end

to sideway

if pxcor < 0 [ set heading 270 ]                                                           
  if pxcor > 0 [ set heading 90 ]

end
```

this is just apseudocode. now my question is that how to count the number of turtles in pxcor >0 and pxcore<0?

example

```
if pxcor > 0
counter ++;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
count turtles with [ pxcor > 0 ]
```

`turtles` is just all the turtles. `turtles with [ pxcor > 0 ]` creates a new set that contains just the turtles from `turtles` for which `pxcor > 0` is true. `count` just counts the number of agents in a set.